# David Gemmell's Drenai Series reading order

Tags: suggested-order, david-gemmell, drenai-series

I recently bought David Gemmell's *Legend*, suggested by a bookseller which also informed me that it was part of independent novels within a whole world. However, she told me there were details featured from one book to another, so I wonder if there is a recommended reading order on this series?

Sometimes, the reading order may not follow the publishing order, so according to readers experience, what should I read next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is a suggested reading order at the [Gemmell Awards](http://www.gemmellawards.com/) website, from memory this order is the suggested one after a conversation that was had with David Gemmell himself

The order is shown as

**Drenai Saga:**

- Waylander (1986)
- Waylander 2: In the Realm of the Wolf (1992)
- Waylander 3: Hero in the Shadows (2000)
- The First Chronicles of Druss the Legend (1993)
- The Legend of Deathwalker (1996)
- White Wolf (2003)
- Legend (1984)
- King Beyond the Gate (1985)
- Quest for Lost Heroes (1990)
- Winter Warriors(1997)
- The Swords of Night and Day (2004)

Personally I would say you have to read the Waylander trilogy in order, but to me reading them by themselves only inspires one to read the other novels.

Comment: Please don't only answer with a link. Instead, please put the relevant information in your answer. Link-only answers are subject to removal.

Comment: Have updated my answer now - sorry for that original entry

Comment: Thanks. To be clear: Is this the order recommended by the author?

Comment: The books, Knights of Dark Renown and Morningstar aren't part of the Drenai Saga.  They are both stand alone novels.  They're both good reads, but shouldn't be part of this answer.

Comment: Just adding that while Morningstar and Knights of Dark Renown aren't part of the Drenai Saga, they do take place in the same world, with some major characters crossing over into the Saga.